# ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Validation (DataAnnotations) on Subobject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, model-validation

Does the ASP.NET MVC 2 model validation includes subobjects?

I have an instance "Filter", from this class:

```
public class Filter
{
    [StringLength(5)]
    String Text { get; set; }
}
```

in my main object:

```
public class MainObject
{
    public Filter filter;
}
```

However, when I do TryValidateModel(mainObject) the validation still works out even if "Text" in MainObject.Filter.Text is longer than 5 characters.

Is this intended, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks:

- Use public properties and not fields on your models
- The instance you are trying to validate needs to go through the model binder for this to work

I think that the first remark needs not much explanation:

```
public class Filter
{
    [StringLength(5)]
    public String Text { get; set; }
}

public class MainObject
{
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
}
```

As for the second, here's when it does not work:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Here the instantiation of the model didn't go through the model binder
    MainObject mo = GoFetchMainObjectSomewhere();
    bool isValid = TryValidateModel(mo); // This will always be true
    return View();
}
```

And here's when it will work:

```
public ActionResult Index(MainObject mo)
{
    bool isValid = TryValidateModel(mo);
    return View();
}
```

Of course in this case your code could be simplified to:

```
public ActionResult Index(MainObject mo)
{
    bool isValid = ModelState.IsValid;
    return View();
}
```

Conclusion: you rarely need `TryValidateModel`.